# iOS: keyboard in notification content extension is pushing up the content

Tags: ios, notifications, keyboard, lockscreen

We have an iOS app that receives push notifications when the user gets a new message and we implemented a notification content extension to render this message (html) on the lockscreen. We have enabled user interaction thus the user can tap inside the content without dismissing/opening the app.

For the *reply to message* action we use a textfield component above the original message that becomes the first responder, so the cursor will be at the top. The problem is that when the keyboard is being shown it will push the view up, and the textfield is no longer visible.

Is it possible to reposition the content back to top or just allow the keyboard to show on top of the notification content without pushing it up?